# Redirect From /index to simple www version htaacces file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect this www.artistictiling.com.au/index  to www.artistictiling.com.au version but when i redirect it by using 
Redirect 301 /index to www.artistictiling.com.au it is showing continuous loop.

any help would be appreciated If possible provide .htaccess rewrite rule for above problem

Answer (score 0):

Then you have a redirect to `/index` you should remove them first before you redirect back to `/`.

Check your `.htaccess` file and other redirects in your project.

Comment: You have an infinite loop if you redirect to /index and back to /

Comment: But there is no redirect to /index. I checked my file there is redirect from /index.html version to www version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to base your on `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.